# Enabling debug symbols in shared library using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

I am creating a shared library using `gcc` and suspect that there may be some memory leaks from the shared library. To debug, I need to enable debug symbols when creating the shared library.

To build, I am using `gcc -g ...` (`-g` is for enabling debug information)

But the library (`*.so` file) size is not changing for both `-g`, and without `-g`.
Besides, I am not getting any useful information from tools like `VALGRIND`.

Can anyone point me the mistake?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your makefile, or the other CFLAGS being used?

Comment: I added -g to CFLAGS and it worked, thanks !!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use `-g` for all the steps (compiling your source files and linking).

Comment: Also make sure you don't specify -s when linking, because this strips debug info.

Comment: The -g flag is not really needed for the gnu linker as the ld man page says: "-g  Ignored.  Provided for compatibility with other tools.". It is only required for the compilation stage.